# Why are not "infamous" and "inflammable" the opposite of "famous" and "flammable"?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, synonyms, antonyms, prefixes

Why are not *infamous* and *inflammable* the opposite of *famous* and *flammable*, like *incomplete, inactivity, inappropriate* and so on?

Comment: What, inflammable means flammable? What a country!

Comment: English is both ingenious and intuitive; however, the genious and tuitive among us must struggle along.

Comment: Also: invaluable

Comment: It needs to be noted that "flammable" is effectively a neologism, having been popularized ca 1960 because of the confusion (in the US , at least) as to the meaning of 'inflammable".  "Non-flammable" is the corresponding antonym.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* I had on my Mac Mini (which was the third edition, last time I checked) reported the following definitions for *in-*:

> in- 1
>   prefix
>   1. (added to adjectives) not: *inanimate* | *intolerant*.
>   2. (added to nouns) without; lacking: *inadvertence* | *inappreciation*.
>
> in- 2
>   prefix
>   in; into; toward; within: *induce* | *influx* | *inborn*.

Looking at the origin of *infamous*, and *inflammable*, I read the following:

> infamous
>   ORIGIN late Middle English: from medieval Latin *infamosus*, from Latin *infamis* (based on *fama* 'fame').

> inflammable
>   ORIGIN early 17th century: from French, or from Latin *inflammare* (see *inflame*).

In both the cases, the words are not built adding the prefix *in-* to existing words.

Comment: but I could argue that they are indeed built by adding the suffix in- to existing words :)

Comment: You are right user733 (except that it is a prefix, not a suffix). They are actually built using the prefix *in-* (even if English borrowed the whole word including the prefix).  It is just that there are two prefixes that look like "in", and both came from Latin, and both were the source of these two words we borrowed.  In both cases it is *in* #2 from kiamlaluno's NOAD quotation.  This morpheme *in* is etymologically the same *in* that the English prefix *en* comes from, in words like "enable", "enclose", "encrypt", etc.

Comment: Just to confuse things even more, in french the word for nonflammable is ininflammable, with the two different prefixes used one before the other.

Comment: That is exactly what happens in Italian, with _ininfiammabile_.

Comment: This doesn't explain the meaning of the prefix *in-* in the context of *infamous*.

Comment: @sondra.kinsey There is no *in-* prefix in *infamous*.

Comment: @apaderno: Your own answer would seem to disagree: "from Latin infamis (based on fama 'fame').", as does [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/infamous) It's a Latin prefix in "infamous" just the same as its a Latin prefix in "inanimate". "In-" meaning "not" [isn't usually used for new words](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/57840/whats-difference-between-and-un) in English.

Comment: @sondra.kinsey That is in Latin. In English, *infamous* is not seen as *in-* followed by *famous*.

Answer (score 38):

(Just to be contrarian.)

1. The word *infamous* **is** the opposite of *famous*! Just as the opposite of *reputed* is *disreputed* rather than *obscure*, and the opposite of *hot* is *cold* rather than *not hot*, the opposite of *famous* (having "good" fame) is *infamous* (having "bad" fame, having infamy, ill-famed).
2. The word "flammable" is newer than *inflammable* and does not exist, for instance, in Indian English. Historically, the only word was *inflammable*, dating to at least the 16th century. "Flammable" did not exist. Note that we still say *inflammatory speeches* not **flammatory speeches*, *inflammation of the skin* not **flammation of the skin*, etc. (However, *flammation* "exposure to fire" actually exists in the OED and is marked as obsolete, the only quote dating to 1646.)
   The word "flammable" was invented around 1813, but it didn't catch on, and some time in the 19th century was pretty much dead: The 1913 Webster's dictionary [marks the word "flammable" as obsolete](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/WEBSTER.sh?WORD=flammable). Unfortunately (IMHO), this word was revived after World War II. (See [this letter](http://www.word-detective.com/120398.html#flammable). More precisely, the word *flammability* was revived, and then "flammable" followed.)
   The OED entry for *flammability* is:

> flammaˈbility, n.
>     = **inflammability** n. Revived in modern use to avoid the possible ambiguity of *inflammability*, in which the prefix *in-* might be taken for a negative (in- prefix3).

In my opinion, the word *flammable* was unnecessary: there's not much confusion possible in seeing, on a gas/petrol tanker, the words "Warning: Highly inflammable". It seems to me there's more confusion about the meaning of *inflammable* when the word "flammable" exists, than when it doesn't. But where "flammable" is already common enough, it's safe—and recommended—to use it.

Comment: Hot and Cold are on a spectrum where it can be logically said that the opposite of one end of the spectrum is its counterpart at the other end equidistant from some midpoint of that spectrum. Famous and infamous are not the same; both are famous but one is good fame and one is bad fame. I don't think it really makes sense to talk about them in terms of "opposites".

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: "Famous" and "infamous" are also on a similar spectrum: the midpoint (like "neutral temperature" in case of hot/cold) would be obscurity. I don't see the difference you speak of: is it just the existence of a word ("fame") for being at the extreme of the spectrum, unlike no word for extreme temperature? [If a spectrum denotes "how hot" something is, then something "hot" could be said to have a +ve value and something "cold" a -ve one. Similarly a spectrum denoting how much of a good opinion the world has about someone has "famous" corresponding to +ve and "infamous" to -ve.]

Comment: It's more of a two-dimensional spectrum: One dimension for well-known vs. obscure, and one dimension for +ve vs. -ve.

Comment: @Dan: Why isn't that the same for hot and cold? You could say: one dimension for extreme temperature vs. normal, and one dimension for positive vs. negative.

Comment: Your *reputed* example works, but I'm also not sure about *hot* vs *cold*. The question is about how the modifier *-in* has two different senses - you don't really say *un-hot* or *in-hot* or *dis-hot* at all, regardless of whether or not it means something other than *cold*.

Comment: @Hannele: I used the "hot" vs "cold" example to illustrate the meaning of "opposite"; it had nothing to do with the prefix "in". My point was that "infamous" *is* the opposite of "famous", just as "disreputed" is the opposite of "reputed" (both are a kind of repute: one is good repute and one is bad repute), and just as "hot" is the opposite of "cold" (both are extremes of temperature, in different directions). Under this argument, there is no different sense of "in-" here; it's still just being used for the opposite.

Comment: My point is that your example *disreputed* highlights that there are at least two distinct opposites for the word (good vs bad, and known vs unknown). There isn't really a direct opposite for *hot* that doesn't just mean *cold*, and this isn't really a place where you need to demonstrate the general meaning of *opposite*.

Comment: @Hannele: How does "disreputed" highlight the existence of an opposite to "famous" meaning "unknown"? Alternatively, which example highlights the "unknown" opposite? My entire argument is that "unknown" is *not* an opposite of "famous" (as that would be equivalent to saying that the opposite of "hot" is "at room temperature" rather than "cold", or that the opposite of "beautiful" is "plain" rather than "ugly", or that the opposite of "tall" is "medium height" rather than "short", etc.).

Comment: But an opposite of *famous* is *unknown*. It's not a midpoint on a scale between *famous* and *infamous*, because you can be both very good and very bad at something, and *also* not be very well known for it. The fact that *infamous* has a meaning other than *unknown* highlights that there are two different opposites - similarly, *disreputed* meaning something other than *not having reputation*.

Comment: @Hannele: In the answer, I made an argument why the opposite of famous is infamous, not unknown. You're basically ignoring that argument, also ignoring the examples (it's ironic that you question the need to invoke the examples, given this) and flatly stating that the opopsite is *unknown,* simply by assertion. I don't know what to say. :-) **It is exactly my point** that infamous does *not* mean "unknown, and disreputed does *not* mean "not having reputation". The argument is that just as disreputed is a valid opposite and means bad repute, infamous *is* a valid opposite and means bad fame.

Comment: Yes! And I am saying that *famous* has **two opposites** - both *infamous* and *unknown* - and each has a different meaning. Consider how politics - often divided only into left and right-wing  - can also be described by [authoritarian vs liberal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_compass), where there are both authoritarian left-wingers and liberal right-wingers. **There is more than one opposite, and they mean different things**.

Comment: @Hannele: I can agree with that actually. :-) Seems like you agree that "infamous" *is* an opposite of "famous" though, not just "unknown", which was the point of the "hot" vs "cold" example. I'll edit this answer later today to make that clearer.

Answer (score 7):

The folklore with the term "flammable" was that it had to be invented precisely because people read "inflammable" as "won't burst into flame" (and granted, "inflame" really isn't a word you get to hear everyday). The blame should be apportioned to the safety people I suppose. :)

Comment: Ultimately, it means that no company or person should ever use the word *inflammable* under any circumstances, because in any situation where it is crucial enough to mention, you don't want to leave any doubt :)  Stick with *flammable* and *nonflammable*.

Comment: On a personal note, "flammable" grates on my ears. :) If I were to address a bunch of foremen and construction workers, however, I would grit my teeth and say something like "paint is flammable!"

Comment: Good point. At least the words has gotten me some free beers from bets over the years. 

As a country of good english language education, everyone know about the prefix in- to reverse the meaning. Most people who just rely on logic are flabbergasted when they look it up and realize their defeat... =)

Comment: Somewhat related: The U.S. Navy does not use the word unload (take cargo out of a ship) because in can be confused with onload (put cargo aboard a ship).  Rather, only the words load and off-load are used.