# Difference between "inflammable" and "flammable"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are not infamous and inflammable the opposite of famous and flammable like incomplete, inactivity, inappropriate and so on?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/why-are-not-infamous-and-inflammable-the-opposite-of-famous-and-flammable-like-in)

I'm very confused by the existence of these apparently antonymous words, which actually mean the same thing. Which word should I use? Can both words be used interchangeably?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are not infamous and inflammable the opposite of famous and flammable like incomplete, inactivity, inappropriate and so on?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/why-are-not-infamous-and-inflammable-the-opposite-of-famous-and-flammable-like-in) and [Where did prefix exceptions originate?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/where-did-prefix-exceptions-originate)

Comment: My first thought was this quote http://simpsons.neoseeker.com/wiki/Dr._Nick_Riviera

Comment: @RegDwight To be honest, ykombinator's answer is even better than Shree's answer on the other one, it's a shame this question had to be closed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both words mean the same thing, i.e. that something can be set on fire. 
The reason for the confusion comes from people thinking that the prefix *in-* of *inflammable* is the Latin negative prefix *in-* (which is commonly used in English, e.g. *indecent*). In actual fact, in this case it is derived from the Latin preposition *in*. It's easier to think about it with the word *inflame*. If you can inflame something, it is inflammable (inflame-*able*).

In most cases, it is better to just use *flammable* to avoid confusion and accidents.

Comment: Definitely use *flammable* if you're concerned about the safety of illiterates.

Answer (score 4):

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flammable) advises using only **flammable** to give warnings:

> Usage Note: Historically, *flammable*
>   and *inflammable* mean the same thing.
>   However, the presence of the prefix
>   *in-* has misled many people into
>   assuming that *inflammable* means "not
>   flammable" or "noncombustible." The
>   prefix *in-* in *inflammable* is not,
>   however, the Latin negative prefix
>   *in-*, which is related to the English *un-* and appears in such words as *indecent* and *inglorious*. Rather, this
>   *in-* is an intensive prefix derived from the Latin preposition *in*. This
>   prefix also appears in the word
>   *enflame*. But many people are not aware
>   of this derivation, and for clarity's
>   sake it is advisable to use only
>   *flammable* to give warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct in all situations.

Same with regardless and irregardless (although the latter is more informal, and often declared incorrect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irregardless)

Comment: But *irregardless* isn't really a word by most people's definitions! It's just a bit of historical US "country-bumpkin-speak", whereas *flammable* and *inflammable* are both perfectly valid words. In principle they're totally interchangeable, but I don't think I've ever seen a tanker carrying *Inflammable Liquid*. Personally, I associate *Inflammable* with stuff that's intended to burn (under appropriate control, of course). *Flammable* is more for stuff you really want to avoid accidentally setting alight.