# Why doesn't the prefix "in" in "invaluable" mean "un-" as in other adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, prefixes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did prefix exceptions originate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/where-did-prefix-exceptions-originate)

- efficient
- accessible
- consistent
- articulate
- considerate
- conceivable
- convenient

- inefficient
- inaccessible
- inconsistent
- inarticulate
- inconsiderate
- inconceivable
- inconvenient

However *valuable* to *invaluable* sits alone, like a trap, not merely an inconvenient irregularity but seemingly almost inconceivable that it's not a deliberate inconsistency, causing an inconsiderate degree of inaccessibility for the inarticulate. So English is even more inefficient and inaccessible than it would otherwise be.

Or is there a logical reason why *invaluable* doesn't mean *unvaluable*?

Comment: This sounds like peeving disguised as a question.

Comment: I'm natively English. I don't have a problem with the languege as a whole. I quite enjoy it although I havn't to be fair tried other languages. I just don't see the point in things like this. Also it is a question, if anyone knows why it's as it is.

Comment: You "don't see the point" is why I think you're peeving.

Comment: The point? English isn't designed, it just kinda happens.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6776

Comment: cf. flammable vs. inflammable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for the prefix *in-* in *invaluable* is that it originally meant simply "impossible to value". It has somehow acquired the more specific meaning that it is impossible to value *because its value is infinitely high*. So there is no illogicality here.

Cf. *innumerable*, "impossible to count (because the number is infinite)", *immense*, "unmeasured (because it is too great to be measured)", etc. etc.

When you think about it, it is not even the word *invaluable* that has shifted in meaning the most, but rather *valuable*: it evolved from "capable of being valued" to "capable of being valued highly (because its value is high)". It is mostly the shift in the meaning of *valuable* that pulled the former opposites together, though I concede that *invaluable* bears some of the blame too.

Cf. *numerous* "having a *high* number", instead of simply "having a number", etc.

Comment: :¬o You'r right. Valuable should be 'able to be valued'. The modern usage is the wrong one.

Comment: Sorry. I removed the original comment because I realised I was thinking about it wrongly. I meant 'dosn't have one' as being similar to 'not', but as you say it's not the 'in' prefix thats changed, it's the meaning of the word valuable.

Comment: @alan2here: Agreed. But "wrong" is a bit too strong: better call it "irregular".

Answer (score 1):

There is no inconsistency. "Valuable" means "having a value (which can be calculated)". "Invaluable" means "having an incalculable (enormous) value". The prefix "in-" refers to the calculability, not the magnitude, of the value.

Comment: So *priceless* means no price that can be calculated and *worthless* mean no worth that can be calculated. But it is not obvious why *invaluable* should mean infinite value rather than zero value.

Comment: Right, it not obvious by simply looking at the prefix. For that matter, why shouldn't "valueless" mean the same as "invaluable"? But this is a bit like asking why "cat" shouldn't mean a small rock. The answer is simply: because it doesn't. It's an accident of history.