# Prefix im- is for opposite or asserting

Tags: meaning, prefixes

Is the prefix *im-* used in a negative sense, as in, the opposite of the word following it, e.g.

- *Impenitent* = "*not* penitent"

Or it is used in the positive sense that supports the word following

- *Impassive* = more or less same meaning as *passive*.

When do I know if it is opposite and when not?

Comment: You know it by learning all words by heart. Just like everyone else, everywhere, in the entire history of the language. There is no other way. There can't be.

Comment: What are we to do with [pertinent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pertinent) and [impertinent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impertinent)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be noted that the prefix *im-* is really just the prefix *in-* with the consonant adjusted because of the consonant that follows.

As for *passive* and *impassive*, it's a quirk of the history of the meaning that they've ended up with similar meanings. Originally *passive* meant *feeling pain* and *impassive* meant *not feeling pain*. The former came to mean *not active* while the latter came to me *without emotions*.

But you're right, as [other cases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/why-are-not-infamous-and-inflammable-the-opposite-of-famous-and-flammable) show, *in-* is a particularly difficult prefix to discern meaning from for words you haven't encountered before.

Comment: Especially because there are **two** prefixes _in-_, both from Latin. One _in-_ means 'not', as in _illiterate_ or _irreverent_ (negative _in-_ also assimilates before L and R), but the other _in-_ means 'inside', like _inhabit, internal, intromission_. They were homophones in Latin, too, and English borrowed all those Latin words, so we got both prefixes too.